# MinGW on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: mingw, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to install MinGW on Windows 7 on a 64 bit system, but after the installation is complete, some basic files like `stdio.h` are missing.

I install the same MinGW package on Windows XP 32bit and there is no problem (I have `stdio.h`...)

I use `mingw-get-inst-20111118.exe` found at [MinGW download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)

Should I do something differently on a 64 bit system (or Windows 7)?
Should I try MinGW 64?

Answer (score 2):

Perform these steps:

- Open a *MinGW Shell* from the start menu shortcut at *All Programs* >
  *MinGW* > *MinGW Shell*:
- Run the following command:

  `mingw-get install mingwrt`
- Verify that the installation was successful by checking for `stdio.h`
  at:

  `C:\MinGW\include\stdio.h`

Comment: I tried it, but I get error that `mingwrt` is already installed.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, the last thing I wanted is to make you mad :) After trying what you suggested, still I cannot find `stdio.h` file in `\Mingw\include` folder. Io tried to install MinGW on a different PC with Windows 7 (64 bit) but this one does not exhibit the same problem. So I am not sure what is going on here. Next thing I am going to try is to copy the `MinGW` folder from working system to the other one and see what will happen. Thanks for your time, and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `mingw-get install gcc` today and now I see `stdio.h` is installed on my system. I am sure I've tried this before. I think something has been fixed in Mingw installer recently that resolves the problem.