# stdio.h is missing on my MinGW installation

Tags: mingw

I've installed it with the MinGW installer from the website, installed gcc's packages but somehow I'm still missing **stdio.h**.

I don't know how to list all of my installed packages. But I've installed **gcc**, **mingwrt**, **w32api** and such.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Read the comments - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497999/mingw-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: @shk I've already tried that and, as with the question's author, it didn't solved it. stdio.h is still missing from C:\MinGW\include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a corrupt mingwrt-dev package that was being download from some mirror that I cannot remember. mingw-get doesn't complain if the package is corrupt and even prints that the installation was successful.

Downloading from another mirror and reinstalling fixed the issue.